# Why does Android Studio Arctic Fox fail to sync my project

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio Arctic fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2 fails with th following error in `idea.log`:

```
ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't resolve library via LibraryId(name=Gradle: com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.3, tableId=com.intellij.workspaceModel.storage.bridgeEntities.LibraryTableId$ProjectLibraryTableId@4b9d4a4e) 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't resolve library via LibraryId(name=Gradle: com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.3, tableId=com.intellij.workspaceModel.storage.bridgeEntities.LibraryTableId$ProjectLibraryTableId@4b9d4a4e)
```

I have a suspicion that the concrete lib in question is a bit random. Before I upgraded from Patch 1 to Patch 2, the error said:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't resolve library via LibraryId(name=Gradle: androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0@aar, tableId=com.intellij.workspaceModel.storage.bridgeEntities.LibraryTableId$ProjectLibraryTableId@73f6fd09)
```

Gradle syncs just fine - the sync finishes with `BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s` . It's definitely Android studio that is the problem. Any Idea?

Comment: I had similar error:

`ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't resolve library via LibraryId(name=Gradle: androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0@aar, tableId=com.intellij.workspaceModel.storage.bridgeEntities.LibraryTableId$ProjectLibraryTableId@40dcc5a4)`

I don't know why it is caused!

Answer (score 5):

File > Invalidate Cache and Restart solved the problem

Comment: The problem is that I have to go through it each time I'm changing my `gradle`